# cut: the delimiter must be a single character

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to get the branch name of all my branches on my repo but I am getting this error

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Here is my script file

```
git branch -a | grep -v HEAD | cut -d  ' /' -f3 | grep -v master
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

`' /'` is two characters (space and slash), and as the error message says, it must be a single character.

If you really need to cut the strings according to `' /'`, a possible solution is to replace `' /'` by a single character that you know it cannot appear in the output of `git branch -a | grep -v HEAD`. Let's say `'%'`. The full command would then be:

`git branch -a | grep -v HEAD | sed "s/ \//%/ | "cut -d'%' -f3 | grep -v master`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get the name of all your local branches and
your remote-tracking branches.

I would do this instead:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' \
    'refs/heads/**' 'refs/remotes/*/**' | grep -v master
```

The two `**` are for refs with `/` in their names.